# System.InvalidCastException while adding User control to CustomTaskPane

Tags: c#, outlook, user-controls, vsto, customtaskpane

I am trying to add a `User control` on `Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myCustomTaskPane` by using following line:

```cs
myUserControl = new IssueAddition(categoryList);
myCustomTaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myUserControl, "Issue Reporting Pane");  --> errornous line
myCustomTaskPane.Visible = true;
```

I am getting the below exception:

```
 An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.Implementation.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: 
Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.ICustomTaskPaneSite'.
This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{3CA8CD11-274A-41B6-A999-28562DAB3AA2}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

I am unsure about what could be the cause for `System.InvalidCastException` exception.

Edit 1: Adding the code of the latest implmentation which is also giving the same error:
I have a separate class,`IssueAddition` inheriting `System.Windows.Forms.UserControl` class like below:

```cs
   public partial class IssueAddition : UserControl
    {
        public IssueAddition()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public IssueAddition(List<String> categories)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            foreach (string cat in categories)
                this.i_issue_category.Items.Add(cat);
        }
        public string IssueCategoryInputText
        {
            get { return (string)this.i_issue_category.SelectedItem; }
            set { this.i_issue_category.SelectedItem = 
            this.i_issue_category.FindStringExact(value); }
        }
        public string MessageInputText
        {
            get { return this.i_error_message.Text; }
            set { this.i_error_message.Text = value; }
        }
}
```

And it's being used in `ThisAddIn.cs` like below:

Declaration:

```cs
#region Instance Variables

        Outlook.Application m_Application;
        internal static List<Outlook.Explorer> m_Windows; // List of tracked explorer windows.
        internal static List<Outlook.Inspector> m_InspectorWindows;// List of traced inspector windows.
        private IssueAddition myUserControl; <--
```

Usage:

```cs
public async void AddIssue()
        {
            List<String> categoryList = new List<String>();
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                categoryList = dAO.loadCategoryAsync("all").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                if (categoryList == null)
                    categoryList = new List<String>();
                myUserControl = new IssueAddition(categoryList);
                Add add = new Add(MyCustomControlAdd);
                Globals.ThisAddIn.myUserControl.Invoke(add);                
            });
        }
        delegate void Add();

        private void MyCustomControlAdd()

        {
            Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myUserControl, "test").Visible = true;
        }
```

Edit 2: I also tried `Invoke` method on but it also throws same exception. I am unable to understand how to overcome this problem.

```cs
       public async void AddIssue()
        {
            List<String> categoryList = new List<String>();
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                categoryList = 
               dAO.loadCategoryAsync("all").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                if (categoryList == null)
                    categoryList = new List<String>();
                myUserControl = new IssueAddition(categoryList);
                if (!Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.CheckAccess())
                    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myUserControl, "test").Visible = true;

                    }));
                else
                    Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myUserControl, "test").Visible = true;

                    }));
            });
        }
```

**Edit 3**: Adding the code changes to make it work as suggested by the accepted answer:
Add `Dispatcher _dispatcher;` instance variable in `ThisAddIn.cs`.
Intialise it in `ThisAddIn_Startup` function:

```cs
       private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            _dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        }
```

Usage:

```cs
public async void AddIssue()
        {
            List<String> categoryList = new List<String>();
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                categoryList = dAO.loadCategoryAsync("all").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                if (categoryList == null)
                    categoryList = new List<String>();
                myUserControl = new IssueAddition(categoryList);
                _dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myUserControl, "test").Visible = true;
                }));
            });
        }
```

Comment: Where and when do you try to create a new task pane instance in Outlook? Does it work with a newly created empty user control?

Comment: I am creating this UserControl in one of the function triggered on a click. Like when user clicks a button, this control will be initialised and add to TaskPane to become visible to on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you are calling that code on a secondary thread.

If you absolutely must do so from a secondary thread, use `Dispatcher.Invoke` (where `Dispatcher` object is retrieved from `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` on the main thread).

Comment: This code is part of ThisAddIn class. I tried Dispatcher.Invoke function too on userControl but that also gave the same error. Will update that code too here. Is there any other way i can add my User control to CustomeTaskPane ?

Comment: When and how is this code called?

Comment: After your suggestion, i tried adding these lines after initialising myUserControl object. ```Dispatcher.CurrentDispatchher```: ```Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                {
                    Globals.ThisAddIn.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myUserControl, "test").Visible = true;

                }));```  But this also gives the same error.

Comment: Also, to get hold of Main thread, i read that ```Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke``` is needed. However, I can't use ```Current``` property of ```Application``` which is of type ```Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application```. This gives ```'Application' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no accessible extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument of type 'Application' could be found.```

Comment: `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke` is useless - you are essentially saying "take this code and execute it on the current thread". You don't need a dispatcher for that. Capture `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` into a dedicated variable on the main thread when your addin is loading `_dsipatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher`. Then when your are about to create a control, use `_dispatcher.Invoke`

Comment: I don't know where `Application.Current.Dispatcher` comes from. I certainly never suggested that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that your user control instance passed to the [Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.customtaskpanecollection.add?view=vsto-2017#microsoft-office-tools-customtaskpanecollection-add(system-windows-forms-usercontrol-system-string)) method is inherited from the [System.Windows.Forms.UserControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.usercontrol?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) class.

The following code example demonstrates how to create a custom task pane by using the `Add(UserControl, String)` method. The example also uses properties of the `CustomTaskPane` object to modify the default appearance of the custom task pane.

```
private MyUserControl myUserControl1;
private Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane myCustomTaskPane;

private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    myUserControl1 = new MyUserControl();
    myCustomTaskPane = this.CustomTaskPanes.Add(myUserControl1,
        "New Task Pane");

    myCustomTaskPane.DockPosition =
        Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionFloating;
    myCustomTaskPane.Height = 500;
    myCustomTaskPane.Width = 500;

    myCustomTaskPane.DockPosition =
        Office.MsoCTPDockPosition.msoCTPDockPositionRight;
    myCustomTaskPane.Width = 300;

    myCustomTaskPane.Visible = true;
    myCustomTaskPane.DockPositionChanged +=
        new EventHandler(myCustomTaskPane_DockPositionChanged);
}
```

Comment: I implemented the above solution. I am getting same exception,  ```Additional information: Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type ```. Updated the code for reference.